# GoogleAnalytics track time between events

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am using GA on an Android app but this question can be relevant to all platfroms.

I track an event the usual way:

```
t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
.setCategory(getString(categoryId))
.setAction(getString(actionId))
.setLabel(getString(labelId))
.build());
```

Is there a way to see a report of how much time has passed between such 2 events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I eventually did was tracking the time in the code and then report it like this:

```
long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timingValue = time2 - time1;
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.TimingBuilder()
            .setCategory(timingCategory)
            .setValue(timingValue)
            .setVariable(timimngVariable)
            .setLabel(timingLabel)
            .setCustomDimension(1,1)
            .setCustomMetric(1, timingValue).build());
```

This will give you a report in the App Speed section of the Behavior section in the reporting tab.

However, another problem arose regarding custom reporting of timed events which is described here:  [GoogleAnalytics HitBuilders.TimingBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324977/googleanalytics-hitbuilders-timingbuilder)